# Is there a way to automatically update the .Net Winforms AssemblyFileVersion as part of the Visual Studio build process?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2019

We have a .Net WinForms applicaton. The application gets built directly in Visual Studio.

**We are tracking the following in the AssemblyInfo.cs file:**

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("OurApplicationName")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2023.04.13")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("OurApplicationVersion")]
```

Is there a way I can automatically update the **AssemblyFileVersion** as part of a pre-build event in our build process?

Comment: Hi, I found the [How to programmatically update AssemblyInfo.cs as a prebuild event post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57666790/how-to-programatically-update-assemblyinfo-cs-as-a-pre-build-event-visual-studi). Usually you should enter the corresponding powershell command in the Pre-build event command line box. At the same time, you need to create the corresponding powershell script.

Comment: @GetValue - thanks for the feedback/ideas. I didn't realize that PowerShell was an option. I ended up going old school and created a simple .Net console app that get's called with parameters as part of my prebuild events.